# Updating gridview through stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

This is my Master table Recruiter in which I have set two primary keys(Recruiter_ID,Status] to work them as composite key...
I am binding this table to gridview to make updations on table(i.e Update operation)
I dont want to actually update the table fields through update command ...
before performing updating a record its status field value should be made 0 or greater than 1 but not 1  ...status=1 denotes it is the current record..

This is my stored procedure to update record ...it is executing perfectly in sql server management studio..

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Update_recruiter] 
(
     @Recruiter_ID      int,
     @CompanyName       varchar(50),
     @CompanyAddress    varchar(50),
     @Location          int,
     @ContactNumber     varchar(50),
     @Email             varchar(50),
     @CompanyWebsite    varchar(50)
 )
as 
 begin
 declare @temp int 
 select  @temp = max ([Status]) 
 from New_Recruiter 
 where Recruiter_ID = @Recruiter_ID 
 update New_Recruiter 
 set [Status] =  @temp +1
 where  Recruiter_ID = @Recruiter_ID and  [Status] = 1

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT New_Recruiter ON

 insert into New_Recruiter
 (
             Recruiter_ID,
             Company_Name ,
             Company_Address ,
             Location ,
             Contact_Number ,
             Email ,
             CompanyWebsite,
             [Status],
             [DateTime] 
)
 values
 (
        @Recruiter_ID,
        @CompanyName ,
        @CompanyAddress ,
        @Location ,
        @ContactNumber ,
        @Email ,
        @CompanyWebsite ,
         1, 
         getdate()
)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT New_Recruiter OFF;
end
```

but when I attach this procedure to grid view ...it gives error that Procedure or function Update_recruiter has too many arguments specified.

here is grid view aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataSourceID="UpdateReSqlDataSource1"  CssClass="grid" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="Recruiter_ID">
 <Columns>
 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Recruiter_ID" HeaderText="Recruiter_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Recruiter_ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Company_Name" HeaderText="Company_Name" SortExpression="Company_Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Company_Address" HeaderText="Company_Address" SortExpression="Company_Address" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_Number" HeaderText="Contact_Number" SortExpression="Contact_Number" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyWebsite" HeaderText="CompanyWebsite" SortExpression="CompanyWebsite" />
</Columns></asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UpdateReSqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RCConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="sp_Display_Recruiter" UpdateCommand="Update_recruiter" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Recruiter_ID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyAddress" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyWebsite" Type="String" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I personally don't like this built in functionality because there is no way to test it and would suggest to update and fill the gridview from code behind. Anyway you say it is giving this error on attach, I am not completely sure but you should check your select stored procedure, because when you are attaching it should be the one that is fired.

Comment: Can you share the stored proc code of update ?